# Setting up a reverse proxy from Apache to Node.js

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, node.js

I am attempting to setup a reverse proxy from Apache to a Node.js/Express.js app listening on port 8000. This server has cpanel installed but I have ssh access and pretty much ignore cpanel. I added the following to the top of my `httpd.conf`.

```
<VirtualHost 97.74.237.44:80>
    ServerName node.dealerdigitalgroup.com
    ServerAlias www.node.dealerdigitalgroup.com
    DocumentRoot /home/mydomain/public_html/node
    UseCanonicalName Off
    Options -Indexes
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I restarted `httpd` and started my app. Now when I try and access `node.dealerdigitalgroup.com` I get served the index page but it takes a longer then it should and node logs a long list of errors.

```
> node app.js
Listening on port 8000
GET /403.shtml 404 6.307 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 1.113 ms - 9
GET /500.shtml 404 0.566 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.266 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.262 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.291 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.341 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.863 ms - 9
GET / 200 205.543 ms - 170
GET /403.shtml 404 0.418 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.212 ms - 9
GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 67.533 ms - 110
GET /503.shtml 404 0.366 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.508 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.266 ms - 9
GET /400.shtml 404 0.375 ms - 9
GET /503.shtml 404 0.500 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.181 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 0.367 ms - 9
GET /403.shtml 404 9.250 ms - 9
.....
```

It just goes on like that until I kill my node app.

When I visit `node.dealerdigitalgroup.com:8000` everything works as it should so it must be some configuration problem with apache.

```
> apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:80           is a NameVirtualHost
         default server s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1191)
         port 80 namevhost s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1191)
127.0.0.1:443          s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1241)
97.74.237.44:443       is a NameVirtualHost
         default server shiftperformanceparts.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1139)
         port 443 namevhost shiftperformanceparts.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1139)
         port 443 namevhost s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1241)
97.74.237.44:80        is a NameVirtualHost
         default server node.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:27)
         port 80 namevhost node.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:27)
         port 80 namevhost 97.74.237.44 (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:276)
         port 80 namevhost dealerdigitalgroup.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:298)
         port 80 namevhost dealerdigitalmarketing.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:336)
         port 80 namevhost dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:374)
         port 80 namevhost lakeautobody.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:412)
         port 80 namevhost riversidedodge.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:450)
         port 80 namevhost shiftperformanceparts.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:488)
         port 80 namevhost fakedomain.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:526)
         port 80 namevhost theaddept.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:565)
         port 80 namevhost homeloansdoctor.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:603)
         port 80 namevhost tradeestimator.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:641)
         port 80 namevhost pedderautogroup.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:679)
         port 80 namevhost temeculanissan.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:717)
         port 80 namevhost cardinero.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:755)
         port 80 namevhost dashboard.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:793)
         port 80 namevhost racewaynissan.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:831)
         port 80 namevhost testbuild.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:869)
         port 80 namevhost peddernissan.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:907)
         port 80 namevhost forms.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:945)
         port 80 namevhost hemetcdjr.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:983)
         port 80 namevhost lakecdjr.tradeestimator.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1021)
         port 80 namevhost node.dealerdigitalgroup.com (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1059)
         port 80 namevhost fitness19covina.dealerdigitalgroup.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1097)
         port 80 namevhost s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:1191)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:*                    is a NameVirtualHost
         default server s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:288)
         port * namevhost s97-74-237-44.secureserver.net (/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:288)
Syntax OK
```